# Cannot access callback in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a theme in wordpress and I have WooCommerce installed. When viewing the shop page there is a different header or rather no header at all (In any case it is not the one I designed nor the one that shows upon first visiting the url). The error at the top of the page shows

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/band/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 213
```

This is the call stack

Call Stack

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  232984  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2   0.0002  235792  require( '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/band/wp-blog-header.php' )  ../index.php:17
3   0.4528  36798136    wp( )   ../wp-blog-header.php:14
4   0.4528  36798400    WP->main( ) ../functions.php:873
5   0.4566  36808800    WP->query_posts( )  ../class-wp.php:611
6   0.4566  36809288    WP_Query->query( )  ../class-wp.php:540
7   0.4566  36817776    WP_Query->get_posts( )  ../query.php:3836
8   0.4573  36834600    do_action_ref_array( )  ../query.php:2377
9   0.4574  36836056    call_user_func_array:{/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/band/wp-includes/plugin.php:571} ( )    ../plugin.php:571
10  0.4574  36837200    WC_Query->pre_get_posts( )  ../plugin.php:571
11  0.4574  36837792    WC_Query->product_query( )  ../class-wc-query.php:294
12  0.4577  36840584    apply_filters( )    ../class-wc-query.php:438
13  0.4578  36841976    call_user_func_array:{/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/band/wp-includes/plugin.php:213} ( )    ../plugin.php:213
```

From plugin.php

```
do { foreach( (array) current($wp_filter[$tag]) as $the_ ) if ( !is_null($the_['function']) ){ $args[1] = $value; $value = call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 1, (int) $the_['accepted_args'])); } } while ( next($wp_filter[$tag]) !== false );
```

I tried debugging on my local machine and values for variables corresponding to the frame when stopped at line 213 of plugin.php but might somebody know what is going wrong just by looking?

Update:
I commented out these lines of code in the functions.php and the error went away

```
/*
function products_per_page_category( $count ) {
    return $count;
}

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);
*/



//add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', products_per_page_category( 20 ));
```

however it is still not using the same header as the rest of my template.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: What other code do you need to see, sorry if the last post is messy. Was trying to format it.

Comment: Your code where you insert the hook/filter. this looks like WP code you just posted.

Comment: Yeah I have not written any plugin code, the only thing I did do was move the WooCommerce templates to the themes folder so that I could make custom edits without changing source code.

Comment: Does it work properly when you move the files back?

Comment: No it does not, I tried but did not expect it to work because I did not actually delete them from their original folder. This is just a way to override the default template.  
One thing I do not understand is that call_user_func_array() expects a method call as it's first parameter. From debugging I determined that that method in this case is _config_wp_siteurl($url = '' ), which simply returns the name of the blog and can be found in functions.php. This is a valid function but the error is saying it is not a valid callback.

Comment: Solved. The header issue and the php error were unrelated. I removed those lines of code from function.php and found where to change the template in archive-products.php. The line that says <?php get_header('shop'); ?>. I replaced it with the header call that is in the index.php, same thing with single-product.php for the single item pages in case anyone else is wondering. Here is a link that helped.  http://thewebdesignforum.co.uk/topic/1900-woocommerce-template-pages/

Comment: Yet still, can anyone answer why those lines of code that I commented out in the functions.php file were causing the error? Namely the error that says `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given`